# db2: how to remove the decimal from number column?

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions, where-clause

A very simple query which work

```
select avg(price) from cars where type = 'electric';
```

the result is

```
1                                
---------------------------------
                45000,00000000000
```

I want to remove the ,00000000000 to obtain

```
   1                                
    ---------------------------------
                    45000
```

I have tried cast and round but without success.
I'm on Db2

This nice ltrim works fine for all type of cars

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(price,'0',' ')),' ','0') from cars;
```

but using with avg return the string with the 00000

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(avg(price),'0',' ')),' ','0') from cars where type = 'electric';
```

the result is..

```
45000.00000000000
```

:(
Only the , is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cast`ing this value should just work:

```
select cast(avg(price) as int) as avg_int
from cars 
where type = 'electric';
```

Answer (score 2):

Casting as an integer as suggested by another answer will work.

However, keep in mind that

1. you'll be truncating any decimal values.
2. you're converting from one type to another.

You can resolve #1 by casting after `ROUND()`

```
select int(round(avg(price),0)) as avg_int
from cars 
where type = 'electric'
```

You can resolve #2 by using `DECIMAL()` or `ZONED()` with zero for scale depending on the original column type.

```
select dec(avg(price),10,0) as avg_dec
from cars 
where type = 'electric'
```

And of course `ROUND()` could be used with `DECIMAL()` or `ZONED()` also...